# Centos abruptly restarts - same main process killed by TERM signal everytime

Tags: linux, centos, linux-kernel

I have a centos6.9 running on a VM that went crazy this morning. It started abruptly rebooting. In the beginning the reboot gap was 10 minutes exactly, then it narrowed down to 5, then 3 and now it sometimes varies. Below are messages from /var/log/messages.

```
May 10 18:40:01 hwmaster01 init: tty (/dev/tty1) main process (2126) killed by TERM signal
May 10 18:40:01 hwmaster01 init: tty (/dev/tty2) main process (2128) killed by TERM signal
May 10 18:40:01 hwmaster01 init: tty (/dev/tty3) main process (2130) killed by TERM signal
May 10 18:40:01 hwmaster01 init: tty (/dev/tty4) main process (2132) killed by TERM signal
May 10 18:40:01 hwmaster01 init: tty (/dev/tty5) main process (2134) killed by TERM signal
May 10 18:40:01 hwmaster01 init: tty (/dev/tty6) main process (2136) killed by TERM signal
May 10 18:40:07 hwmaster01 ntpd[1767]: ntpd exiting on signal 15
May 10 18:40:08 hwmaster01 rpcbind: rpcbind terminating on signal. Restart with "rpcbind -w"
```

*after some time

```
May 10 18:45:02 hwmaster01 init: tty (/dev/tty1) main process (2137) killed by TERM signal
May 10 18:45:02 hwmaster01 init: tty (/dev/tty2) main process (2139) killed by TERM signal
May 10 18:45:02 hwmaster01 init: tty (/dev/tty3) main process (2141) killed by TERM signal
May 10 18:45:02 hwmaster01 init: tty (/dev/tty4) main process (2143) killed by TERM signal
May 10 18:45:02 hwmaster01 init: tty (/dev/tty5) main process (2146) killed by TERM signal
May 10 18:45:02 hwmaster01 init: tty (/dev/tty6) main process (2148) killed by TERM signal
May 10 18:45:08 hwmaster01 ntpd[1772]: ntpd exiting on signal 15
May 10 18:45:08 hwmaster01 rpcbind: rpcbind terminating on signal. Restart with "rpcbind -w"
```

*after some time

```
May 10 18:52:01 hwmaster01 init: tty (/dev/tty1) main process (2124) killed by TERM signal
May 10 18:52:01 hwmaster01 init: tty (/dev/tty2) main process (2126) killed by TERM signal
May 10 18:52:01 hwmaster01 init: tty (/dev/tty3) main process (2128) killed by TERM signal
May 10 18:52:01 hwmaster01 init: tty (/dev/tty4) main process (2131) killed by TERM signal
May 10 18:52:01 hwmaster01 init: tty (/dev/tty5) main process (2133) killed by TERM signal
May 10 18:52:01 hwmaster01 init: tty (/dev/tty6) main process (2135) killed by TERM signal
May 10 18:52:09 hwmaster01 ntpd[1767]: ntpd exiting on signal 15
May 10 18:52:10 hwmaster01 rpcbind: rpcbind terminating on signal. Restart with "rpcbind -w"
```

There are no new stressing tools running. It is master node in a hadoop cluster environment in which there are 4 nodes on separate VM but on same hardware. All the VMs seem to work fine on hardware level but this master node crashes and stops all the services.
Anyone familiar with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach `strace` to that main process. It will tell you by which process it gets killed.

Comment: I just updated kernel related packages using yum and seems like it solved my problem. No reboots for a day. Will confirm after few days. Thanks